# Angular render html before rxjs response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to show some html code based on response,but HTML render before receive response.

**Html:**

```
 <div *ngIf="medias.length > 0">
    some text
 </div>

<div *ngIf="!medias.length > 0">
    some other text
</div>
```

**Ts:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMedias();
}

medias: Array<T> = [];

getMedias() {
   this.controllerApiService
   .getById()
   .subscribe(data => {
     this.medias = data
   });
}
```

According to the code above firstly show "some other text" and after receive response,show "some text"

I trying to handle with skip() and skipWhile() but nothing change.

Comment: when you call to `this.getMedias()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple problems here.

First, use RxJS to its full potential. Then, use Angular to its full potential too. Finally, use the correct conditions to make it all work.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="medias$ | async as medias">

  <div *ngIf="medias.length; else noMedia">
    Some media : {{ medias.length }}
  </div>

  <ng-template #noMedia>
    No media
  </ng-template>

</ng-container>
```

```js
medias$ = this.getMedias().pipe(shareReplay(1));

getMedias() {
  return this.controllerApiService.getById();
}
```

Comment: What is the use of shareReplay(1) here?

Comment: `shareReplay` is used to avoid redoing the http call at every new subscription. In that particular case I don't think this is useful, but I got the habit of putting it almost everywhere just for safety, I would suggest you do the same